# Using navigation component Load fragment inside a fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack-navigation

In Home Fragment I am having xml as

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavi"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/bottm_navi" />

        <meow.bottomnavigation.MeowBottomNavigation
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavi"
            app:mbn_circleColor="@color/white"
            app:mbn_backgroundBottomColor="@color/app_dark_blue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my bottom navigation is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottm_navi"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeBottomOneFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeBottomOneFragment"
        android:name="com.krassier.customer.ui.home.bottom.HomeBottomOneFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home_bottom_one"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_bottom_one" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeBottomTwoFragment"
        android:name="com.krassier.customer.ui.home.bottom.HomeBottomTwoFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home_bottom_two"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_bottom_two" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeBottomFourFragment"
        android:name="com.krassier.customer.ui.home.bottom.HomeBottomFourFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home_bottom_four"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_bottom_four" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeBottomThreeFragment"
        android:name="com.krassier.customer.ui.home.bottom.HomeBottomThreeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home_bottom_three"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_bottom_three" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment2"
        android:name="com.krassier.customer.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment2_to_homeBottomOneFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeBottomOneFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment2_to_homeBottomTwoFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeBottomTwoFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment2_to_homeBottomThreeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeBottomThreeFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment2_to_homeBottomFourFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeBottomFourFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

in homefragment I wrote

```
 findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment2_to_homeBottomOneFragment)
```

when I clicked on bottomnavigation I am trying to load another fragment in homefragment as bottom navigation is in home fragment, but error is:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.krassier.customer:id/action_homeFragment2_to_homeBottomOneFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.krassier.customer:id/homeFragment) label=fragment_home class=com.krassier.customer.ui.home.HomeFragment`

Comment: Simply I am trying to load one fragment in another

Answer (score 0):

At last I followed conventional way

```
private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = activity?.supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction?.replace(R.id.homeFragmentContainer, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction?.commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a fragment, you should try finding the navController this way.

```kotlin
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id. fragment) as NavHostFragment. // the id of your FragmentContainerView
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

You should take advantage of the NavigationUI library and let it handle the navigation fragment change logic for you

```kotlin
        binding.bottomNavi.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    currentDestination?.getAction(direction.actionId)?.run { navigate(direction) }
}

fun NavController.safeNavigate(
    @IdRes currentDestinationId: Int,
    @IdRes id: Int,
    args: Bundle? = null
) {
    if (currentDestinationId == currentDestination?.id) {
        navigate(id, args)
    }
}
```

This crash occurs when you make multiple calls the navigate method.

https://nezspencer.medium.com/navigation-components-a-fix-for-navigation-action-cannot-be-found-in-the-current-destination-95b63e16152e

Comment: that's one cause, but pretty sure his first call to the navigation method also crashed because he used the incorrect navController

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only just change the fragment like Fragment Transaction using Navigation component, you could do it like this:

```
private fun getNavController(): NavController {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)
    return navController
}

private fun changeFragment(@IdRes viewId: Int) {
    getNavController().popBackStack()
    getNavController().navigate(viewId)
}

// how to use it
changeFragment(R.id.homeBottomFourFragment)
```